# Ajax GET request Laravel 5.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following in my routes.php:

```
  Route::get('/displayphotos', function()
  {
    return view('displayphotos')->with('photos', photo::all());
  });
```

I basically have a javascript code section which initially uses the $photos that the displayphotos routes returns using photo::all()... This does work and everything.
I have this running on a 10000 interval.

```
   setInterval(function() {
      _.forEach({!! $photos !!}, function(value, key) {
        photos_array.push(value.name);
      });

      photos_array = _.uniq(photos_array);

      More code here...

      }, 10000);
```

So essentially what I want to accomplish is having that $photos get refreshed in here when the interval kicks in it would grab the latest values from $photos which is stored in the database. I am assuming this means I need to make an ajax request somehow using GET? Would I need to add a controller method for this? or can it be done inline somehow?

Can anyone help with how I would accomplish what I am asking?

Comment: imagine the page request :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an AJAX request because php code executes in the server side and your UI is in the client side, so the operation all runs only once time.

You can try this:

```
 Route::get('/displayphotos', function()
 {
   return json_encode(photo::all());
 });
```

To display a JSON array and use a AJAX request to consume that every interval

Comment: Okay so this does seem to work but running into issue:
      $.ajax({
         url: 'photos_json',
         success: function(data) {
          photos = data;
          console.log(photos);
          _.forEach(photos, function(value, key) {
            photos_array.push(value.name);
          });

My problem is that photos is not seeming to be a json object or something it is getting undefined for lojax

Comment: @AlexWinter your url is `displayphotos` not `photos_json`

Comment: I got it. I added photos_json route.
Just needed to add JSON.parse to turn string it was returning into object.
Rusty with things right now with laravel/javascript right now thanks for the help!

Comment: json_encode is not necessary here. Laravel will convert it to json for you so just `return Photo::all();`